# Rotate a vector

Tags: xna, c#, camera, rotation, vector

I want my first-person camera to smoothly change its viewing direction from direction d1 to direction d2. The latter direction is indicated by a target position t2.

So far I have implemented a rotation that works fine but the speed of the rotation slows down the closer the current direction gets to the desired one. This is what I want to avoid.

Here are the two very simple methods I have written so far:

```
// this method initiates the direction change and sets the parameter
public void LookAt(Vector3 target) {

        _desiredDirection = target - _cameraPosition;
        _desiredDirection.Normalize();

        _rotation = new Matrix();

        _rotationAxis = Vector3.Cross(Direction, _desiredDirection);

        _isLooking = true;
    }


// this method gets execute by the Update()-method if _isLooking flag is up.
private void _lookingAt() {

        dist = Vector3.Distance(Direction, _desiredDirection);

        // check whether the current direction has reached the desired one.
        if (dist >= 0.00001f) {

            _rotationAxis = Vector3.Cross(Direction, _desiredDirection);
            _rotation = Matrix.CreateFromAxisAngle(_rotationAxis, MathHelper.ToRadians(1));


            Direction = Vector3.TransformNormal(Direction, _rotation);
        } else {

            _onDirectionReached();
            _isLooking = false;
        }
    }
```

Again, rotation works fine; camera reaches its desired direction. But the speed is not equal over the course of movement -> it slows down.

How to achieve a rotation with constant speed ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
_rotationAxis = Vector3.Cross(Direction, _desiredDirection);
_rotation = Matrix.CreateFromAxisAngle(_rotationAxis, MathHelper.ToRadians(1));
```

As `Direction` & `_desiredDirection` change to be pointing in nearly the same direction (as they converge), The smaller the magnitude of `_rotationAxis` will be. It will still be pointing in the proper direction to be the axis but will be a shorter length. That is the nature of the cross calculation.

The guts of the `CreateFromAxisAngle` method uses the length of the axis as a factor in the amount of rotation it results in. When the axis has a length of 1, it results in the correct amount of rotation.

So if you were to normalize `_rotationAxis` between the two lines I quoted above, you would get a constant rotational rate.

Answer (score 6):

I'd suggest letting the framework do all of the work for you. Start by calculating a rotation matrix for your start and end orientations, and convert them both to quaternions. You only do this *once* at the start of the movement and store the values.

```
Matrix start = /* calculate current rotation matrix */;
Matrix end = /* calculate desired rotation matrix */;
Quaternion startQ = Quaternion.CreateFromRotationMatrix(start);
Quaternion endQ = Quaternion.CreateFromRotationMatrix(end);
```

Now interpolate between these two orientations using spherical linear interpolation. There's a method for it so you don't have to implement anything yourself:

```
// Animate the progress parameter between 0 and 1
Quaternion currentQ = Quaternion.Slerp(startQ, endQ, progress);
```

Finally recalculate your direction using the quaternion above, or convert it back to a rotation matrix. Something like this for instance:

```
Vector3 direction = Vector3.Transform(Vector3.Forward, currentQ);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed advise! I will try that after lunch ;)

Comment: `Quaternion.Slerp` Is it just me, or does that sound like a name in either a really bad or really good fantasy novel? Minus the dot, of course.